# Creating Entry in SQLLite DB won't work with Prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, sqlite, prisma

I just started working with Prisma and SQLLite and wanted to create an entry, but it won't work.
What I get is an error message that I don't understand, and I couldn't find any solution online.

Creating Entry

```
const collection = await prisma.collection.create({
    data: {
        name: name,
        chain: chain.toString(),
        transactions: {}
    }
})

const dataJson = await JSON.parse(data)

const transactions = dataJson.map(async tx => {
    await prisma.transaction.create({
        data: {
            collection: {
                connect: {
                    id: collection.id
                }
            },
            collectionId: collection.id,
            price: tx.price,
            timestamp: tx.blockTime,
            token: tx.tokenMint,
            txHash: tx.hash,
            marketplace: tx.source
        }
    })
})

prisma.collection.update({
    where: {
        id: collection.id
    },
    data: {
        transactions: transactions
    }
})
```

Prisma Models:

```
model Collection {
   id            Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
   name          String
   chain         String
   transactions  Transaction[]
}

model Transaction {
   id            String      @unique()
   collection    Collection  @relation(fields: [collectionId], references: [id])
   collectionId  Int
   price         Int
   priceAssumend Boolean     @default(false)
   timestamp     Int
   token         String
   txHash        String
   marketplace   String
}
```

When I run `npm run build` I get the following exception:

[image: ErrorMessage]

If you need any more information/code snippets to help, just leave a comment :)